# How to wait until event is handled in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

Let's imagine we have such code:

```
public class MyProcess
{
    private Process _process;
    public event EventHandler OnFinish;
    public MyProcess(string pathToExe)
    {
         _process = new Process();
         _process.StartInfo.FileName = pathToExe;
    }
    public int Start()
    {
         _process.Exited += _processExited;
         _process.Start();
         return _process.Id;
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
         _process.Stop();
    }
    private void _processExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         OnFinish?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class MyProgram
{
    private static int stoppedProcs = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var proc = new MyProcess("foo.exe");
         proc.OnFinish += proc_OnFinish;
         proc.Start();
         proc.Stop();
         //Wait here to display 1 instead of 0
         Console.WriteLine(stoppedProcs);
    }

    private static void proc_OnFinish(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         stoppedProcs++;
    }
}
```

I create and launch process. Then I want to stop it and continue only after I handle the event. The problem is I do not invoke event by myself as it is done by OS. How can I understand that event handlers are finished?

Comment: Is your `Process` class `System.Diagnostics.Process`? I find no `Stop` in `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Comment: Have a look into [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.8) or [ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=netframework-4.8) if you want to stick to Event Pattern. You could as well switch to Task based async ([TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap)), though.

Comment: @LouisGo Yes. My mistake, I use Kill()

Comment: @LouisGo I do not understand what I can await here. I do not call async methods. I kill a process and the OS signals that the process is exited and after that the handler is invoked

Comment: @Alexander Sorry, Fildor's suggestions are more suitable in your case, I'll remove my comment to prevent confusing.

Comment: Ok, thank you all, I'll check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answering my question.
The problem was solved easily with @Fildor' s suggestion to use `ManualResetEvent`

```
public class MyProgram
{
private static int stoppedProcs = 0;
private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var proc = new MyProcess("foo.exe");
     proc.OnFinish += proc_OnFinish;
     proc.Start();
     proc.Stop();
     //Wait here to display 1 instead of 0
     mre.WaitOne();
     mre.Reset();
     Console.WriteLine(stoppedProcs);
}

private static void proc_OnFinish(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     stoppedProcs++;
     mre.Set();
}
}
```

Comment: This solution may be easy, but is it robust? What will happen if the `proc_OnFinish` handler in invoked before the line `mre.WaitOne()`? Is there a guarantee that this will never happen?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias , good question. As I learned this does not matter. If handler is invoked before `mre.WaitOne()` and calls `mre.Set()` then main thread will not be blocked.

Comment: You are right, I had forgot about that! So you have no race conditions, provided that the `proc_OnFinish` will run only once. The line `stoppedProcs++` indicates that this may not be the case though! Btw take a look at the [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment) method for thread safe incrementation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to wait synchronously (blocking the current thread), just expose through your class the [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit) method.

```
public void WaitForExit()
{
    _process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*To extend answers mentioning `Task` and `await` stuff*

If you want to turn the wait into an async flow, you could combine the `Exited` event with a `TaskCompletionSource` like this:

```
public static class ProcessExtension
{
    public static Task WaitForExitAsync(this Process proc, Action callback)
    {
        return new WaitForExitExt(proc, callback).WaitTask;
    }

    class WaitForExitExt
    {
        private TaskCompletionSource<int> _tcs;
        private Action _callback;

        public WaitForExitExt(Process proc, Action callback)
        {
            _callback = callback;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            if (proc.HasExited)
            {
                _tcs.TrySetResult(proc.ExitCode);
            }
            else
            {
                proc.Exited += OnProcessExited;

                // Process already exited by the time the handler was attached.
                if (proc.HasExited)
                {
                    proc.Exited -= OnProcessExited;
                    _tcs.TrySetResult(proc.ExitCode);
                }
            }
        }

        public Task WaitTask => _tcs.Task;

        private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var proc = (Process)sender;
            proc.Exited -= OnProcessExited;

            _callback();

            _tcs.TrySetResult(proc.ExitCode);
        }
    }
}
```

The above extension enables the ability to run a `callback` once the process exited, and the `callback` is guaranteed to be run before the task is completed, so you could use it in your code like:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Start();

var task = process.WaitForExitAsync(() => Console.WriteLine("Exited"));
process.Kill();
await task;

Console.WriteLine("Task finished");
```

And the output is:

```
Exited
Task finished
```